# Printing Response from Binance Order

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

How do I print the response from an order like below?

```
order = client.order_limit_buy(
        symbol='ADABUSD',
        quantity=buy_quantity,
        price=price,
        newOrderRespType = 'ACK'
    )
```

I wish to get the orderId from it so I can check its status...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/59e3c8045fa13ca0ba038d4a2e0481212b3b665f/binance/client.py#L1326) is an example how response looks. It is [JSON-like `dict` object](https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/blob/59e3c8045fa13ca0ba038d4a2e0481212b3b665f/binance/client.py#L326).

So order ID may be taken by: `order["orderId"]`